# DB2 move primary key to another column

Tags: sql, db2, primary-key

I have a table:

```
create table A (
    KEY VARCHAR(1024) not null
);
```

where `KEY` is primary key. Now I want to create another autoincrement column `ID` BIGINT, drop exiting primary key constraint and make created column `ID` as primary key.

How to do this without loosing my data?

Sure I can use temporary table, but try to find right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE A DROP PRIMARY KEY;

ALTER TABLE A ADD COLUMN ID BIGINT NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT 0;

ALTER TABLE A ALTER COLUMN ID SET GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1);

REORG TABLE A;

UPDATE TABLE A SET ID = DEFAULT;

ALTER TABLE A ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE A ADD ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;` got me an error : Error: An unexpected token "IDENTITY" was found following "AS".  Expected tokens may include:  "<left_paren>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.8.86
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104

Comment: @coms Try the modified version I made from looking at this thread - http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1650358-adding-identity-column-existing-table.html

Comment: error at line: `ALTER TABLE A ALTER COLUMN ID SET GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1);` Error: ALTER TABLE "DB2ADMIN.A" specified attributes for column "ID" that are not compatible with the existing column.. SQLCODE=-190, SQLSTATE=42837, DRIVER=4.8.86
SQLState:  42837
ErrorCode: -190

Comment: What platform are you running DB2 on? z/OS? Linux/Unix/Windows? iSeries?

Comment: Windows 7 x64. Probably it is a driver bug, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the option at http://www.channeldb2.com/profiles/blogs/how-to-add-identity-column-to and it worked